# Excel VBA. Find the index of the value selected in a Data Validation list?

Tags: excel, list, validation, indexing

Excel for Microsoft 365, corporate version.

I have a dropdown list made from the Data Validation process.
There is no name ( top left corner ) attached to it.

=> What is the best way to collect the index of the selected value ?

Thank you

Don't even know where to start...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the cell with your dropdown list is in A1.

Suppose the range with your data validation is E1:E7.

In cell B1, use this formula: `=MATCH(A1,$E$1:$E$7)`